# Unexpected modification of dictionary

Tags: c#, algorithm

Can anyone explain to me why when I create dictionary `Dictionary<char, char[]> dictionary` then I Initialize this dictionary with some objects. After initialization, I want to get some keys based on changed values:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += 2)
    {
        try
        {
            char[] firstValue = new char[]{};
            char[] secondValue = new char[]{};
            dictionary.TryGetValue(text[i], out firstValue);
            dictionary.TryGetValue(text[i + 1], out secondValue);

            char temp = firstValue[4];
            firstValue[4] = secondValue[0];
            secondValue[0] = temp;

            newString += dictionary.First(x => x.Value == firstValue).Key;
            newString += dictionary.First(x => x.Value == secondValue).Key;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            newString += text[i];

        }
    }
```

After this code, the dictionary has modified values.

Comment: For me it sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Initially, what have you tried to achieve with your code?

Comment: Can you add some initialisation and `text` value that we can see the problem with?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your code it´s impossible to reproduce that issue. I can´t see anything that may change the dictionaries content.

Comment: I want to make simple 6 bit-increment register with a dictionary.

Comment: "After this code, the dictionary has modified values" well, yes, you modify them. In your code. You can step through it and watch.

Comment: I know, can I create a dictionary with non-modifiable values?

Comment: And still this is unclear why would you need to do all this. I guess, you are experiencing some problems with reference objects. So, when you take `char[]` from dictionary and change it, you actually change the same object, because array is a reference object.

Comment: I just don't know why the dictionary change value.

Comment: An Array (like char[]) is a reference type, so `firstValue` points to the same object that is stored in your dic, so when you change one, the other gets modified too.

Comment: @Magnetron Ok Its clear now. Thanks

Comment: Also note that, as this is a reference type, `x.Value == firstValue` will compare refences, not the array elements one by one.

Answer (score 2):

An Array (like char[]) is a reference type, so `firstValue` points to the same object that is stored in your dictionary, so when you change one, the other gets modified too. If you want a copy, you could use `Array.Copy`. Also, if you want to compare if the values of the array are the same, you sould use `SequenceEquals` instead of `==`, as this will check if the references are the same and the other determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type.

```
char[] firstValueTemp;
char[] secondValueTemp;
char[] firstValue;
char[] secondValue;
dictionary.TryGetValue(text[i], out firstValue);
dictionary.TryGetValue(text[i + 1], out secondValue);
Array.Copy(firstValueTemp, firstValue, firstValueTemp.Length);
Array.Copy(secondValueTemp, secondValue, secondValueTemp.Length);
char temp = firstValue[4];
firstValue[4] = secondValue[0];
secondValue[0] = temp;

newString += dictionary.First(x => x.Value.SequenceEqual(firstValue)).Key;
newString += dictionary.First(x => x.Value.SequenceEqual(secondValue)).Key;
```